# Texture Loader Looping (THREE.JS R76)

Tags: javascript, three.js, textures, loader

I am making a 3D Portfolio grid with Three.js and am having issues loading textures onto existing spheres. Each sphere has a color and a bump map and the bump map needs to be removed and texture changed on a trigger. The balls are children of a Three.3DObject.

This is the code I am using...I end up with no texture and just Matrix3 Inverse warnings. I don't know if that is a memory leak.

```
function loadPortfolioPieces(){
    for (var i = portfolioBallArray.length; i > 0; i--) {
        loader.load(
            "http://localhost/test/" + portfolioObject[i].texturePath,
            function(texture){
                ballObject.children[i].material.bumpMap = null;
                ballObject.children[i].material.map = texture;
                ballObject.children[i].material.needsUpdate = true;
            },
            function ( xhr ) {},
            function ( xhr ) {
                console.log( 'Failed to load texture' );
            }
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Hard to help with just the code you have given. What is `ballObject`? Does it relate to `portfolioBallArray`? But, I suspect you are facing the [closure inside a loop problem](https://www.google.com.au/?gws_rd=ssl#q=javascript+closure+in+a+loop)

Comment: though I'm not sure the closure problem explains the Maxtrix3 warnings

Comment: Hello again 2pha! So...ballObject = new THREE.Object3D is a global variable and the portfolioBallArray is an array I put certain ballObject children inside as there are more objects in the scene then portfolio pieces. I will try using scene.getObjectByName("ballObject") instead to be sure of the issue. Could scaling an object to 0 cause Matrix3 warnings?

Comment: So in trying scene.getObjectByName("ballObject") I have the same effect. The ball child disappears....ie texture gets replaced but doesn't show new texture.

Comment: Hey 2pha, I figured it out thanks to your hints. I was changing the texture of a different ball (an invisible one thanks to scaling to 0...which was a temp solution for removing them from the scene altogether - there's like over a 1,000 balls). Thank you once again!